# 'This study' or 'The present study'?

Tags: word-usage

In writing up a dissertation, which one of the following should I use:

1. **This study** identifies the importance of ...
2. **The present study** identifies the importance of ...

Comment: This study, as I'm sure there are many studies being written presently. How strange would it be to read that dissertation in ten years? ;)

Comment: A common problem in academic writing: authors do have to decide between "this paper", "the present paper", "the current paper", "our paper", etc. to denote the piece actually being written.  Some of these terms seem clumsy or inaccurate, others (such as "this") are highly ambiguous. I am quite curious whether there's a justifiable stand in this quandary.

Comment: This cannot be answered except by personal opinion. (Unless you have a style guide that recommends one, in which case you should tell us about it.)\

Comment: How stuffy do you want to sound?  (They are equivalent, save for the fact that the second avoids using "this", which is considered nearly as impolite as saying "I" or "me" in such a study.)

Answer (score 1):

'The present study' is generally preferred to distinguish the present work from other studies being referred to, especially in the near vicinity of the reference to 'the present study' - is it simply a formulaic way of distinguishing between your own study and that of others. If there is no such ambiguity possible (and keeping in mind tired/busy readers), especially where one has just mentioned 'the present study', 'this study may be acceptable and, in some instances, preferable.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You could consider combining the two answers copying one of them and paste it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice example, from here - http://www.uefap.com/writing/genre/introd.htm:

"However, even though many studies have reported an increased use of computers in education, there has been very little research reported on the effectiveness of such use. The purpose of the present study is therefore to ascertain the effectiveness of using computer-assisted instruction as compared to traditional classroom instruction in an EAP writing class"

Answer (score -1):

To me, "This Study" gives us specifically no inkling into other studies on the concerned field, rather leaves us in the dark.

On the otherhand, "the present study", 
at the onset, makes it clear that there have been other studies, however, the the present one is concening / dedicated to.........

THIS STUDY depends mostly on readers' presumption about other studies.

THE PRESENT STUDY keeps clear of such ambiguities/ vagueness.

Answer (score -1):

I have reviewed grant proposals for 20+ years, and thousands of papers. I have also been funded 20 times over, and have over 200 peer reviewed publications. I find "the present study" to be a very awkward phrase and have only seen it in use in the last 2-3 years. "This study", "the proposed study", "the study described here" are far more "reader friendly" than "the current" or "the present" study.